# Как перестать мутировать state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня state.items — объект с ключами, которые идут как id, через allIds я нахожу все элементы id, которым нужно изменить дату, но мой action в редюсере меняет сразу дату всем элементам, видимо это связано с мутабельностью и я не знаю, как это исправить... Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```
const allIds = getSubTasksId(Object.values(state.items), payload.id);
allIds.map((id) => (state.items[id].date.current = payload.date));
return {
  ...state,
  items: { ...state.items },
};
```

Comment: Вы не находите, вы меняете всем значение. forEach перебирает все значения и меняет данные

Comment: Покажите, что делает ваша `getSubTasksId` функция, так же какого результата вы хотите достичь

Comment: getSubTasksId выдает массив строк - id. а я уже подставляю их как ключ и обращаюсь к нужному объекту

Comment: Может вам возвращается весь ваш объект?

Comment: возможно, но я знаю точно что решение моей проблемы это перестать мутировать state.items, а как это правильно написать я не знаю

Comment: Что вы понимаете под мутированием в данном случае? Не понятно, какого поведения вы хотите добиться(и как именно работает сейчас, что не устраивает)?

Comment: сейчас он работает по такому способу - https://jsfiddle.net/vinograd1ka/odp1cv08/
но он мутабельный, из-за чего state не может нормально прочитать изменения и сопоставить их

Comment: Никак? Redux сравнивает ссылки на объекты для определение элементов, которые изменились. Используй ReduxToolkit, который работает на иммутабельных данных, что позволяет выборочно изменять любой элемент в любой точке хранилища и не заставлять ререндерить все элементы массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это по идее для redux? давно сним не работал, но вроде эти две вариации должны норм работать.

```js
const objKeys = [1, 2];

let obj = {
  0: {
    title: "a",
    id: 0,
  },
  1: {
    title: "b",
    id: 1,
  },
  2: {
    title: "c",
    id: 2,
  },
};

    let newObj1 = {...obj};
    objKeys.forEach((id) => {
      newObj1 = {
        ...newObj1,
        [id]: {
          ...newObj1[id],
          title: "xyz",
        },
      };
    });
    const newObj2 = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).map((arr) => {
        if (objKeys.includes(+arr[0])) {
          return [
            arr[0],
            {
              ...arr[1],
              title: "ttt",
            },
          ];
        }
        return arr;
      })
    );

    console.log({ newObj2 });
    console.log({ newObj1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ты обязательно хочешь использовать Redux и не переходить на ReduxToolkit, то поправить это можно только на стороне компонентов. Оберни каждый компонент в React.memo и вторым параметров передай функцию.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => <div>{props.a}</div>;
const MyMemoComponent = React.memo(MyComponent, (next, prev) => next.a === prev.a));
```

Если функция вернет true, то ререндера не будет, иначе начнется ререндер. Для более сложных объектов (где надо сравнить массивы и т.п.), пиши либо руками, либо использова lodash - _.isEqual.